# IFrame Like Button gives Suspicious URL error

Tags: url, iframe, facebook-like

I created a Google Sites site and added a Like button using the IFrame option.

The button looks fine but when a user clicks Like, they receive the following error:

**"Sorry, this post contains a suspicious URL: Unknown error".**

It looks like a Facebook like issue, since the error message is displayed in a Facebook branded pop-up window.

My site: **https://sites.google.com/site/wheresthezbfairlane/**

How do I fix this ?

Help!

Thanks
Nick

Answer (score 0):

If you copy pasted the code from the facebook plugin site you might have to remove the 'amp;'s that separate the query strings right after the href attribute.

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?   
 href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com&amp;width=450&amp;height=80&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;layout=standard&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=true&amp;send=true"
scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

So, in the code above just replace '& amp;' with '&'